# Media Files Don't Show Up!

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, stock-android

My Android 4.4.2 can't find media files like music, videos and pictures.

If I try to open them through apps they are not visible, but they are visible in file manager.

Answer (score 0):

When something like this happens to me the first thing I do is stay clam (just a tip if you're stressed it makes things harder). Now just try doing a reboot. To do a reboot you need to hold down the power button until it asks if you want to shut the devicd off tap "Yes" or "Power Off". If that doesn't work try contacting the android developers.

Comment: Reboot resolves the issue, could be, but is there a reason how does it resolves the issue? Please be specific.

Comment: didn't worked,even i did factory reset :(